# Fitting Curve of Gamma Distribution in Hist

Tags: r, plot, histogram, curve-fitting

When I run this:

```
x<-c(73,6,77,81,91,120,150,61,65,68,18,20,23,12,14,18,23,26,26,27,2,3,3,40,41,41,6,10,11,12,37,38,38,6,73,6,51)
a<-1.286486;b<-30.59584

hist(x,breaks=c(0,20,40,60,80,100,120,160),probability = T,xaxt="n")
curve(dgamma(x,a,b),from=0,to=160,col="red",lwd=2,add=T)
```

It should generate the curve of the Gamma Distribution on the histogram. Instead, it just makes a flat line along the x-axis.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a question here? Welcome to StackOverflow! Kindly provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ic3fr0g First of all thanks for welcoming. Sorry, the question is how can i appear the Curve on Hist. If you run it you will see a line down on the x-axis.

Comment: I got a better fit to the non-central chi-squared distribution than to the gamma distribution for this data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your coefficients to the model are incorrect.  The rate parameter should be closer to 0.03.

```
x<-c(73,6,77,81,91,120,150,61,65,68,18,20,23,12,14,18,23,26,26,27, 2,3,3,40,41,41,6,10,11,12,37,38,38,6,73,6,51)

library(fitdistrplus)
model<-fitdist(x, "gamma")
print(model$estimate)
#    shape      rate 
#1.1911710 0.0311047 
a=model$estimate[1]
b=model$estimate[2]    

h<-hist(x,breaks=c(0,20,40,60,80,100,120,160),probability = T)
curve(dgamma(x,a,b),from=0,to=160,col="red",lwd=2,add=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your x vector doesn't contain the realizations of gamma distribution with those parameters (a,b). Try this:

```
a<-1.286486
b<-30.59584
num<-rgamma(1000,a,b)
hist(num,nclass = 100,freq=F)
curve(dgamma(x,a,b),col="red",lwd=2,add=T)
```